# Element Transform Apache Jena

Tags: sparql, jena, arq

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  ?r ?r1 ?r2 ?r3 ?r4
WHERE
  { ?r  ?r1  ?r2 ;
        ?r3  ?r4
  }
```

I want to transform every triple with a optional element like:

```
SELECT  ?r ?r1 ?r2 ?r3 ?r4 ?r5
WHERE
  { {?r  ?r1  ?r2 .} OPTIONAL {?r ?r1 ?r5 .}
    {?r   ?r3  ?r4 .} OPTIONAL {?r ?r3 ?r5 .}
  }
```

basically i am trying to visit all ElementPathBlock, find a triple and transform it into :

`{?r  ?r1  ?r2 .}` transform into `{?r  ?r1  ?r2 .} OPTIONAL {?r ?r1 ?r5 .}`

But I cannot modify an Element while visiting it. Is there a way to do it in Jena?

Comment: I mean, you could use [`ElementTransformer`](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/syntax/syntaxtransform/ElementTransformer.html) or not?

Comment: I solved the issue by extending the [ElementTransformCopyBase](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/syntax/syntaxtransform/ElementTransformCopyBase.html) Class. Then I used [QueryTransformOps.transform](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/sparql/syntax/syntaxtransform/QueryTransformOps.html#transform-org.apache.jena.query.Query-org.apache.jena.sparql.syntax.syntaxtransform.ElementTransform-org.apache.jena.sparql.expr.ExprTransform-) to acheive the transformation I wanted.